# How to deal with dynamic forms with symfony?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, symfony

I want to send a form via ajax, but how print then?

```
ajaxControllerAction(){
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
                ->add('date', 'date')
                ->add('text', 'text')
                ->getForm();
}

$response = array('form' => $form);
    return new Response(json_encode($response));
```

Then I get the form via ajax:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: Routing.generate('ajaxController', {
            }),
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function () {
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#form).html(data.form);
            }
        });
```

My html file:

```
....
<div id="form"></div>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I print this form?

Normaly I use: {{ form(form) }} form print this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create template with one line `{{ form(form) }}` and then render it:

```
return new JsonResponse([
  'form' => $this->renderView('.../yourView.html.twig', compact('form'))
]);
```

Comment: It will work fine, but now I have another problem with it, how to catch the isValid() or isSubmited() on click on the submit button?